# Reuse AdminClient Bean in Kafka Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

To connect to kafka with admin client on port `9094`, i have following two main classes with application.yml as follows:

```
@EnableKafka
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class KafkaSpringApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaSpringApiApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }


}
```

```
package org.kafka.config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig;
import org.kafka.reader.Kafka;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class AdminConfigurer {


    @Autowired
    private Kafka kafkaConfig;



    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> kafkaAdminProperties() {
        final Map<String, Object> configs = new HashMap<>();
        configs.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getBootstrapServers());
        if(kafkaConfig.getProperties().getSasl().getEnabled() && kafkaConfig.getSsl().getEnabled()) {
            configs.put("sasl.mechanism", kafkaConfig.getProperties().getSasl().getMechanism());
            configs.put("security.protocol", kafkaConfig.getProperties().getSasl().getSecurity().getProtocol());
            configs.put("ssl.keystore.location", kafkaConfig.getSsl().getKeystoreLocation());
            configs.put("ssl.keystore.password", kafkaConfig.getSsl().getKeystorePassword());
            configs.put("ssl.truststore.location", kafkaConfig.getSsl().getTruststoreLocation());
            configs.put("ssl.truststore.password", kafkaConfig.getSsl().getTruststorePassword());
            configs.put("sasl.jaas.config", String.format(kafkaConfig.getJaasTemplate(),
                    kafkaConfig.getProperties().getSasl().getJaas().getConfig().getUsername(),
                    kafkaConfig.getProperties().getSasl().getJaas().getConfig().getPassword()));
            configs.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "");
        }
        return configs;
    }


    @Bean
    public AdminClient getClient() {
        return AdminClient.create(kafkaAdminProperties());
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
kafka:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9094
  properties:
    sasl:
      enabled: false
      jaas:
        config:
          username: XXX
          password: XXX
      mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256
      security:
        protocol: SASL_SSL
  ssl:
    enabled: false
    truststore-location: /opt/app/secrets/kafka.consumer.truststore.jks
    truststore-password: XXX
    keystore-location: /opt/app/secrets/kafka.consumer.keystore.jks
    keystore-password: XXX
    key-password: XXX
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class TopicService {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TopicService.class);
  @Autowired
  private AdminClient adminClient;

public void createTopic(Topic topic) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    adminClient
            .createTopics(Collections.singletonList(ServiceHelper.fromTopic(topic)))
            .values()
            .get(topic.getName())
            .get();
  }
}
```

The issue i have seen in logs is
**initially it uses adminclient  config and properly connect to kafka on port 9094 but when I try to create topics, it is using port 9092 rather**

Logs

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-09-07 15:40:20.144  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] org.kafka.KafkaSpringApiApplication      : Starting KafkaSpringApiApplication using Java 18.0.2.1 on DESKTOP-JT3FAGV with PID 71648 (C:\Users\utkarsh\Desktop\gitprojects\kafka-spring-api\target\classes started by utkarsh in C:\Users\utkarsh\Desktop\gitprojects\kafka-spring-api)
2022-09-07 15:40:20.145  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] org.kafka.KafkaSpringApiApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-09-07 15:40:20.245  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-09-07 15:40:20.245  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-09-07 15:40:21.593  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-09-07 15:40:21.675  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 71 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-09-07 15:40:22.660  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-09-07 15:40:22.673  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-09-07 15:40:22.674  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-09-07 15:40:22.860  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/kafka]  : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-09-07 15:40:22.860  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2613 ms
2022-09-07 15:40:23.359  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-09-07 15:40:23.413  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-09-07 15:40:23.621  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-09-07 15:40:23.798  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2022-09-07 15:40:24.398  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-09-07 15:40:24.407  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-09-07 15:40:33.166  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.k.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig    : AdminClientConfig values: 
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9094]
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS

2022-09-07 15:40:47.487  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.1.1
2022-09-07 15:40:47.489  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 97671528ba54a138
2022-09-07 15:40:47.489  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1662545447486
---
---
2022-09-07 15:40:50.300  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@265d12d3, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@14d64eab, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1f2465a0, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2502a969, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6d4146f2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4e059749, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@41c12f62, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@eb03b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7e0bcff7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@19366e29, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@234a3846]
2022-09-07 15:40:50.386  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-09-07 15:40:50.429  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/kafka'
2022-09-07 15:40:50.449  INFO 71648 --- [  restartedMain] org.kafka.KafkaSpringApiApplication      : Started KafkaSpringApiApplication in 31.049 seconds (JVM running for 32.141)
2022-09-07 15:40:56.292  INFO 71648 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/kafka]  : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-09-07 15:40:56.292  INFO 71648 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-09-07 15:40:56.293  INFO 71648 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-09-07 15:41:05.008  INFO 71648 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 1 disconnected.
2022-09-07 15:41:05.009  WARN 71648 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-09-07 15:41:05.055  INFO 71648 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 1 disconnected.
2022-09-07 15:41:05.056  WARN 71648 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-09-07 15:41:05.165  INFO 71648 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 1 disconnected.
2022-09-07 15:41:05.165  WARN 71648 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2022-09-07 15:41:05.413  INFO 71648 --- [| adminclient-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node 1 disconnected.
```

I am not getting the sense of why it is not using the bean again to do administrative tasks.Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

On your kafka server properties, ensure you've defined the advertised listeners on the correct port

```
listeners=SASL_SSL://:9094
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://localhost:9094
```

https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/